# update_user_option not working as expected

Tags: functions, login

So I was looking into the update_user_option() as I need to update an additional field upon registration. So I found this in wp-login.php:

```
update_user_option( $user_id, 'default_password_nag', true, true ); //Set up the Password change nag.

wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $user_pass );
```

Somehow I'm not getting the default password nag upon the first login, which makes me thing update_user_option() doesn't work. Anyway, I've added the following line:

```
update_user_option( $user_id, 'deposit', '5', true );
```

Which of course didn't work (or maybe I'm looking in wrong place). I want to update 'deposit' field in 'wp.users' table.

Could anyone point me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

#### EDIT: WORKING SOLUTION:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_save_extra_fields' );
function my_save_extra_fields( $user_id ) {
global $wpdb;

        $cash=5;
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->users, array('deposit' => $cash), array('ID' => $user_id));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use [`update_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta), I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do though.

#### EDIT (doesn't work):

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_save_extra_fields' );
function my_save_extra_fields( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'deposit', 5 );
}
```

#### EDIT: WORKING SOLUTION:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_save_extra_fields' );
function my_save_extra_fields( $user_id ) {
global $wpdb;

        $cash=5;
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->users, array('deposit' => $cash), array('ID' => $user_id));

}
```

Comment: I was refering to [update_user_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_option) as this is already there (see first code) - I just added my additional line based on that. Is there any difference, and - most importantly - why the default code doesn't work (no nag to change the password)?

Comment: I'm aware that you were using `update_user_option()`, It's in the original post. There is plenty of difference between the two, read the codex or the source code and you'll see, without knowing what you're trying to do, it's nigh impossible to say which is correct to use, I merely suggested it was worth looking at. See if this tutorial helps you at all: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

Comment: this particular profile field is added by the theme. it's already in the wp.users table, and I'm able to change it by updating it with SQL query. I just thought it will be more elegant to use built in function. I'll have a look on the update_user_meta and will get back to you, thanks

Comment: If it's something added by the theme, you should be looking to functions.php, not wp-login.php. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Theme is using a deposit system, users can deposit money with their paypal account and then spend it by posting ads. I want to give people some deposit for start, so they can have their first posting for free. Theme also depends on WP registration, I don't see the point of adding this to functions.php. All I want to achieve is to change an additional field in wp.users upon the registration of user. This is the easiest way to do it - at least for me. If you have another idea I'm listening :)

Comment: Added edited section to solution, you can just hook the user registration process to add the user meta, this way when wordpress updates, you do not have to rewrite any code. Lemmie know if that's not what you were going for.

Comment: no good. it's changing wp_usermeta and the field I need is in wp_users

Comment: As in you added a col to the users table? Because that's not how you should be doing things...it's INCREDIBLY poor practice, especially with a meta table available the way it is here. Use a custom query if you must `$wpdb->insert` will do just fine (if you don't know how to do that, I can modify the answer for that as well), but I strongly suggest you consider using the usermeta.

Comment: Well, I'm not the author of this particular theme, I'm just trying to implement this one feature without the need to rewrite everything when an update comes out. The col is added by theme itself. I will pass on the feedback to the author of the theme, thanks.

Comment: Yea, I suppose if that's the case, I would go for something like a `$wpdb->update()`, since the `user_register` hook is firing after the `$wpdb->insert()` that creates the user. The code you should be looking at is `wp_insert_user()` in /wp-includes/user.php, just in case you want to play around yourself.

Comment: Now you got me lost, I can't find `wp_insert_user()` in /wp-includes/user.php.

Comment: It's on line 1253 in wp3.3.1, the `'user_register'` hook is fired on line 1376 in wp3.3.1.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't see it in first place. But looking at the code I know I won't be able to do it myself. I'm assuming this have something to do with the following lines:
`$data = compact( 'user_pass', 'user_email', 'user_url', 'user_nicename', 'display_name', 'user_registered' );
 $data = stripslashes_deep( $data );`
I don't feel confident enough in messing with this code, would you kindly help me with it?

Comment: No, it should be accessible by the `'user_register'` hook, do you understand how hooks work? More importantly, do you understand why you should avoid directly modifying the wordpress core if at all possible?

Comment: I do understand how hooks work and why I'm supposed to use them instead of making changes to the code. I am however a beginner when it comes to WP. Please see how I modified the hook: http://pastebin.com/21t5Bi4t

Comment: ^^this doesn't seem to be working, still updating wp_usermeta instead of wp_users. Any help what's wrong with it?

Comment: Well, that should be working, but you should be using $wpdb->update(), that way you don't have to deal with any of the prepare() nonsense. Try updating the row to something different from before to make sure that the script is firing correctly and not using the previous one because it's cached or something weird.

Comment: something like this: http://pastebin.com/frD2Bdvq ?

Comment: Yup, I don't see any reason that wouldn't work...and it's definitely better implementation. Did that manage to get the values working for you?

Comment: nope, didn't work at all. edit: I'm adding this into theme's functions.php - is that the way to do it?

Comment: As in it did nothing, or it went to usermeta?

Comment: nothing at all :(

Comment: You're sure the hook is working correctly though? It should only be firing on user creation...do you have a way of testing this? (maybe using `update_option()`)

Comment: every time I modify it, I'm creating a new user, just to be sure it works. no luck so far :(

Comment: Hey, this was flagged by the system as having too many comments. Please take such overly extensive discussions [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'd be happy to, however I can't due to lthe fact that you need 20 reputation to do that.

Comment: Added working solution to the first post. It was a simple typo, I should use 'ID' instead of 'user_id'. Thank you for your help!